# AWS SDK v3 for nodejs, how to get tags of an s3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to extract tags of an s3 bucket with the AWS SDK v3 for Nodejs. This is my code, based on the example how to list all buckets:

```
const { S3Client, GetBucketTaggingCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { fromIni } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini");

const s3 = new S3Client({
  credentials: fromIni({
    profile: 'example-s3'
  })
});


const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await s3.send(new GetBucketTaggingCommand({
      Bucket: "example-bucket"
    }));
    console.log("Success", data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};


run();
```

If I run this, I get

```
Error Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: Bucket.
```

I've read through the documentation of [GetBucketTaggingCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/getbuckettaggingcommand.html). It requires an input of type [GetBucketTaggingCommandInput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/globals.html#getbuckettaggingcommandinput). That is a [json object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/modules/getbuckettaggingrequest.html)  with an required attribute `Bucket`, which I have provided. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like somehing is wrong with your configuration. I might be wrong though.
My config looks like this:

```
 const s3Client = new S3Client({
      region,
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey
      }
    });
```

But I was getting this error when I was applying incorrect command input for the `GetObjectCommand`:

**Wrong:**

```
 s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand({
    client: s3Client,
    params: {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: key
    },
  }));
```

**Right:**

```
s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: key
  }));
```

But my best guess regarding your case is that the issue is in how you're creating your `S3Client` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Error Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: Bucket.

I don't know if it helps but I got that message and the problem was the following:

I forgot to put the 'bucket' name in the .env file, so I was sending the parameters with the 'bucketname' undefined

Comment: The same has happened to me, but in my case, it was a missing env var argument to my lambda in my terraform files.

Answer (score -5):

It means that your Bucket name was not set. Check it.

Comment: set? where? check it? where?

Comment: worst answer ever, what do you mean !!! the bucket wasn't created beforehand !?

Comment: I don't know why this answer is so hated :) I meant that bucket name or key wasn't set. Check your credentials.